# Read an image from a qrc using imread() of OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, imread

I want to read an image from a *qrc* using `imread()` of OpenCV in this way:

```
Mat img = imread(":/TempIcons/logo.png");
```

but the final `img` size is [0x0]. I have also tried:

```
Mat img = imread("qrc://TempIcons/logo.png");
```

but the size I get is the same. I don't want to load the image in a `QImage` to then transform it in a `cv::Mat`. Is there a way to do this in a easy way?. If it is, how can I do it?.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but I have already tried that, but that I obtain from `QFileInfo("qrc.... ").filePath()` is always the same path: ":/TempIcons/logo.png"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @TheDarkKnight pointed out, `imread` is not aware of Qt resources. You can however write your own *loader*,  that uses `QFile` to retrieve the binary data from the resource, and uses `imdecode` (as done internally by `imread`) to read the image:

```
Mat loadFromQrc(QString qrc, int flag = IMREAD_COLOR)
{
    //double tic = double(getTickCount());

    QFile file(qrc);
    Mat m;
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qint64 sz = file.size();
        std::vector<uchar> buf(sz);
        file.read((char*)buf.data(), sz);
        m = imdecode(buf, flag);
    }

    //double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
    //qDebug() << "OpenCV loading time: " << toc;

    return m;
}
```

You can call it like:

```
Mat m = loadFromQrc("qrc_path");
```

or specifying a flag:

```
Mat m = loadFromQrc("qrc_path", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

---

**Performance**

I tried loading the image with `loadFromQrc`, and loading the `QImage` and converting to `Mat` using [this](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/) code, both with and without cloning. `loadFromQrc` results to be 10 time faster then loading a `QImage` and convert it to `Mat`.

Results in ms:

```
Load Mat                :  4.85965
QImage to Mat (no clone):  49.3999
QImage to Mat (clone)   :  49.8497
```

Test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat loadFromQrc(QString qrc, int flag = IMREAD_COLOR)
{
    QFile file(qrc);
    Mat m;
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qint64 sz = file.size();

        std::vector<uchar> buf(sz);
        file.read((char*)buf.data(), sz);
        m = imdecode(buf, flag);
    }
    return m;
}

cv::Mat QImageToCvMat( const QImage &inImage, bool inCloneImageData = true )
{
    switch ( inImage.format() )
    {
    // 8-bit, 4 channel
    case QImage::Format_RGB32:
    {
        cv::Mat  mat( inImage.height(), inImage.width(), CV_8UC4, const_cast<uchar*>(inImage.bits()), inImage.bytesPerLine() );

        return (inCloneImageData ? mat.clone() : mat);
    }

        // 8-bit, 3 channel
    case QImage::Format_RGB888:
    {
        if ( !inCloneImageData )
            qWarning() << "ASM::QImageToCvMat() - Conversion requires cloning since we use a temporary QImage";

        QImage   swapped = inImage.rgbSwapped();

        return cv::Mat( swapped.height(), swapped.width(), CV_8UC3, const_cast<uchar*>(swapped.bits()), swapped.bytesPerLine() ).clone();
    }

        // 8-bit, 1 channel
    case QImage::Format_Indexed8:
    {
        cv::Mat  mat( inImage.height(), inImage.width(), CV_8UC1, const_cast<uchar*>(inImage.bits()), inImage.bytesPerLine() );

        return (inCloneImageData ? mat.clone() : mat);
    }

    default:
        qWarning() << "ASM::QImageToCvMat() - QImage format not handled in switch:" << inImage.format();
        break;
    }

    return cv::Mat();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString url = "...";

    {
        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        Mat m1 = loadFromQrc(url);

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
        qDebug() << "Load Mat: " << toc;

        if(m1.data != NULL)
        {
            imshow("m1", m1);
            waitKey(1);
        }
    }


//    {
//        double tic = double(getTickCount());

//        QImage img;
//        img.load(url);
//        Mat m2 = QImageToCvMat(img, false);

//        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
//        qDebug() << "QImage to Mat (no clone): " << toc;

//        if(m2.data != NULL)
//        {
//            imshow("m2", m2);
//            waitKey(1);
//        }
//    }


//    {
//        double tic = double(getTickCount());

//        QImage img;
//        img.load(url);
//        Mat m3 = QImageToCvMat(img, true);

//        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
//        qDebug() << "QImage to Mat (clone): " << toc;

//        if(m3.data != NULL)
//        {
//            imshow("m3", m3);
//            waitKey(1);
//        }
//    }

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello @Miki. The code you provide is very useful. I tested times and results that convert from `QImage` to `Mat`takes almost the same time that using your code.

Comment: @AngieQuijano gald it helped! Consider in the QImage to Mat test also the time that QImage takes to load the image. I'm checking this right now, so I can update the answer with more details.

Comment: @AngieQuijano, I run some test. Loading a `QImage` and convert to `Mat` is 10 times slower than using this function. Updated the answer with results and test code.

Comment: Great answer @Miki. Naturally, loading from the Qt's resource is going to be much quicker than from a file on disk due to the IO read overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `imread()` loads an image from a file.

In contrast, Qt's resource system compiles the data from images [directly into the program's executable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). Qt's `QFile` operations know that when they are provided a path starting with ":/", it refers to the embedded resources, rather than on disk.

Therefore, I don't think you will be able to use `imread()` to directly access a file that has been placed in Qt's resources.